# insert and update a table using cursor

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cursor

I'm trying to insert records to table

input from information_schema :

```
select table_schema,table_name,table_type
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

expected output:

insert into new table along with DDL of table_name
to get DDL: `select get_ddl('table','INVOICING')`

Can you help me?

```
create or replace procedure proc_getddl
is
v_tableschema varchar(30);
v_tablename varchar(30);
v_tabletype varchar(30);
v_getddl varchar(110);

cursor getddl is 
select table_schema,table_name,table_type,get_ddl('table','INVOICING')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
begin
open getddl;
LOOP
fetch getddl into v_tableschema,v_tablename,v_tabletype,v_getddl;
EXIT WHEN getddl%NOTFOUND;
INSERT INTO backup_table
values (v_tableschema,v_tablename,v_tabletype,v_getddl);

END LOOP;
close getddl;
end proc_getddl;
```

I can use this but I want it to execute for all tables in information schema

Comment: I need to create a procedure in snowflake for this, I'm sorry if I confused with oracle

Comment: I need to create a procedure in snowflake can you help me with that .. I tried dbms_metadata in snowflake but it throwed error as unknown user-defined function

Comment: excuse me, I don't know about snowflake

Comment: can you help me with the logic alone in oracle itself I can change it to snowflake
I need to insert 3 columns use a function on 2nd column and also insert it as 4th column in my backup table

Comment: In Oracle you can use such a query alike `SELECT table_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name) FROM user_tables` after connecting to `MYSCHEMA` ...

Comment: sorry but I need to do this logic in oracle I'm not worried about the schema or exact table name I've just posted for ppl's understanding ..but I need the logic in oracle (I thought execute immediate would work but I couldnt get the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
create table backup_table as 

select table_schema,table_name,table_type,get_ddl('table','INVOICING')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

According to this https://sparkbyexamples.com/snowflake/snowflake-create-table-as-select/

Comment: Hi I want to create a procedure that will insert for all table_name in MYSCHEMA

Comment: if that scripts work, you should be able to do a "create procedure" with it as the basis, as per the link?

Comment: I'm able to insert for 1 table alone using my script .. but I couldnt use get_ddl('table',table_name) as a parameter(table_name here as a parameter) it throws error .. so I need to change the code to dynamically generate this ddl statement for each row(for each table_name) and insert into backup_table